# Showing sub string after specific character

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I want to show sub string after "<". for example I have this statements:

input:

```
" o <kpl"
```

output:

```
"<kpl"
```

input:

```
"h123 l<"
```

output:

```
"<"
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mid()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#mid) for that:

```
QString input = "h123 l<";
int index = input.indexOf('<');
if (index  != -1)
{
    QString output = input.mid(index);
}
```

Comment: I think, you don't need this `if (index != -1)` check.

Comment: Just in case you want to process two cases separately, when characher is found and when is not

Comment: @vahancho: It won’t crash, but if it is needed or not depends on how the code should behave when there’s no “<“. Full string? Empty string?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, my point was that `input.mid(-1)` will return the original string. Yes, the code depends on how missing '<' should be interpreted.